# Powershell Select-Object vs ForEach on Select-String results

Tags: regex, powershell

Let's say I have the results of a call to Select-String in a variable $mat, parsing a regular expression from file contents:

```
$mat = cat errors.txt | Select-String "'(?<code>\w+)'.+ID (?<id>[^:]+)"
```

According to the output of `$mat | Get-Member` the result contains a Matches property of type `Match[]`.

When I execute the following I get all the matches of my regular expression output:

```
PS > $mat | Select-Object -Property Matches

Matches                                                                                                                                                                              
-------                                                                                                                                                                              
{'ACCFWD', ID 16}                                                                                                                                                                    
{'EQASIAN', ID 448}
```

Why doesn't this next block of code using foreach to select the Matches have the same output:

```
    PS > $mat | ForEach { $_.Matches } 


Groups   : {'ACCFWD', ID 16, ACCFWD, 16}
Success  : True
Captures : {'ACCFWD', ID 16}
Index    : 20
Length   : 15
Value    : 'ACCFWD', ID 16

Groups   : {'EQASIAN', ID 448, EQASIAN, 448}
Success  : True
Captures : {'EQASIAN', ID 448}
Index    : 20
Length   : 17
Value    : 'EQASIAN', ID 448
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When displaying properties, PowerShell auto-formats the properties of types that do not have a display format defined in a `*.format.ps1xml` file as a table for up to 4 properties. 5 or more properties displays as a list. When you select the Matches property with `Select-Object`, you are selecting a single property of the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` object. With `Foreach-Object` you are displaying all of the properties for a `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match` object.

Using `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches` will cause the output to look the same as the `Foreach` because it will output `RegularExpressions.Match` objects.

If you place `Get-Member` after both of your examples that produce output you will see that they output different types of objects.

**Edit:** Here is an explanation of the formatting that happens for each command.

```
cat errors.txt | Select-String "'(?<code>\w+)'.+ID (?<id>[^:]+)"
```

The output of `Select-String` is a `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` object which has 8 properties. These properties are not displayed by default because the display format for `MatchInfo` is defined in `PowerShellCore.format.ps1xml` to show the result of `MatchInfo`'s `ToString()` method.

```
$mat | Select-Object -Property Matches
```

In this case, the output of `Select-Object` is a custom `Selected.Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` object with the `Matches` property that was copied from the `MatchInfo` object. Since there is no default display format defined for the `Selected.Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` type, PowerShell auto formats it as a table since it has less than 5 properties (In this case `Matches` is the only property).

```
$mat | ForEach { $_.Matches }
```

In the `Foreach-Object` ScriptBlock, the `Matches` property of the `MatchInfo` object is being output. The `Matches` property is a `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match` which has 6 properties. Since there is no default display format defined for the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match` type, the `Match` objects are displayed as a list because there are more than 4 properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am still confused. The output of the ForEach makes sense; since the Matches property is an array of RegularExpressions.Match objects, I expect to see all of the properties of each Match object. I do not understand though what Select-Object is outputting. I've noticed that I get the equivalent output using ForEach if I nest another ForEach: $mat | ForEach { $_.Matches **| ForEach {$_.Value}** }. Does Select-Object do some sort of expansion of the Match objects? And if so, how am I supposed to know this (where is it documented, where else will this happen?)

Comment: If you look at `help Select-Object` you will see "it copies the values of those properties from the input objects and creates new objects that have the specified properties and copied values.". If you use `-ExpandProperty` it will output objects of the property's type.

Comment: The `Matches` property of the input object is of type `RegularExpressions.Match[]`, not `MatchInfo`. When we say that "the value of this property is copied", since in this case the property is a `RegularExpressions.Match[]`, what I expect as the output of `Select-Object` are objects with a single `Match` property whose value is also of type `RegularExpressions.Match[]`. Where does the `MatchInfo` all of a sudden come from? Thanks!

Comment: `Select-String` returns a `MatchInfo` object. `Matches` is a property of that type. `Select-String` creates a custom object of type `Selected.<Input Type>` and copies the properties that you choose from the original object. In this case it creates a `Selected.Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` object with a 'Matches` property. Again, if you use the `-ExpandProperty` switch `Select-Object` will output a single property as its own object.

Comment: Thanks again. Things are clearer, but I am still confused... If I call `Get-Member` on the output of `Select-Object -Property Matches`, then I see that the `Matches` property is has Definition `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]`, which is equivalent to the definition of the `Matches` of the original `Select-String` output. It seems then that these properties are identical in type, so why does the `Matches` property of `Selected.<InputType>` give different output than the original `Matches` property? Does it have something to do with the select-object's MemberType being a `NoteProperty`?

Comment: I neglected to mention the `*.format.ps1xml` files in my original answer. I've updated the answer with an explanation of each of the outputs. Hopefully it will be clearer now.

Comment: Right, it is a `Match[]` (an array of `Match`). But when arrays are sent down the powershell pipeline they are generally sent one element at a time. So commands further down the pipeline will receive a `Match` object, not the entire `Match[]` array. Run `$m = 'test'| Select-String test`. Then, `$m.Matches.GetType()` will result in `Match[]`, and `$m.Matches|gm` will result in `Match`.

Comment: I notice that the following outputs the same thing as the original foreach: `$mat | Select-Object -Property Matches | foreach {$_.Matches}`. This implies that the object being output by Select-Object is identical to the object being output by my `ForEach` code. I also notice that the output of the `Match.Value` property is the same as what is being output for each item using the original `Select-Object`. It must be that `Select-Object` somehow formats the output differently, even though the input object is identical. Perhaps the output uses the `Value` property using some sort of ducktyping?

Comment: No, it does not imply that the objects are identical, only that they have an identical property, namely `Matches`. `Select-Object` does not format output; PowerShell does the formating. `Match.Value` is not the same as what is displayed by the `Select-String` cmdlet; when selecting from a file, the filename is prepended to the match value.

Comment: What I meant is that the **Matches** properties of both objects are identical! Yet in one case (`ForEach`), the output displays all the underlying properties of the `Matches` property, and in the other case (`Select-Object Matches`) only a quick summary is being output. The `Matches` property of `Selected.Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` seems identical to the original `Matches` property, as indicated by `$mat | Select-Object -Property Matches | foreach {$_.Matches}` which is identical to the original foreach! Where am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer without repeating something I've already written. Maybe this post from the official Windows PowerShell Blog can help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/30/how-powershell-formatting-and-outputting-really-works.aspx

Comment: That link was very helpful. With your help and the help of someone at another forum, I finally figured out the answer: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/5264f048-014b-42d1-a8bd-d246c602d6c0/

Comment: I've figured out why this was so confusing. I kept missing the fact that the output type of select-string had a SELECT prefix - I thought that the output types were the SAME, so it made no sense to say that the displays should be different. Now it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you use -ExpandProperty instead of -Property, then the two outputs will be the same.

```
$mat | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches
```

That works for this particular example, but for accessing a single property, Select-Object -ExpandProperty is still not exactly the same as ForEach in all cases.  I would use ForEach.  Also, see this example:  http://community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/use-foreach-object-instead-of-select-object-expandproperty