# Is it possible to replace Get-Content, ForEach-Object string -match with Select-String cmdlet?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a fixed width file with records in a format as follows

```
DDEDM2018890                                                                 19960730015000010000
DDETPL015000                                                                 20150515015005010000
DDETPL015010                                                                 20150515015003010000
DDETPL015020                                                                 20150515015002010000
DDETPL015030                                                                 20150515015005010000
DDETPL015040                                                                 20150515015000010000
```

the first 3 characters identify the record type, in the above example all records are of type `DDE` but there are also lines of a different type in the file.

the following regular expression with named capture groups parses the relevant information from each record for my purpose (notice it also filters down to `DDE` record types:

```
DDE(?<Database>\w{3})\d{2}(?<CategoryCode>\d{2})(?<CategoryId>\d{1})\d\s+\d{8}\d{3}(?<Length>\d{3})
```

*play with this regex on [this excellent online parser](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)*

I have written a script that uses the `Get-Content`, `ForEach-Object` and `Select-Object` cmdlets to convert the fixed width file into a csv file.

**I wonder if I could replace the `Get-Content` and `ForEach-Object` cmdlets by a single `Select-String` cmdlet?**

```powershell
#this powershell script reads fixed width file and generates a csv file of the relevant & converted values

#Prepare HashSet object for Select-Object to convert CategoryCode and append with CategoryId
$Category = @{
    Name = "Category"
    Expression = {
        $cat = switch($_.CategoryCode) 
        {
            "50"{"A"}
            "54"{"C"}
            "60"{"F"}
            "66"{"I"}
            "74"{"M"}
            "88"{"T"}
        } 
        $cat+$_.CategoryId
    }
}

gc "C:\Path\To\File.txt" | % { 
        if($_ -match "DDE(?<Database>\w{3})\d{2}(?<CategoryCode>\d{2})(?<CategoryId>\d{1})\d\s+\d{8}\d{3}(?<Length>\d{3}).*$")
        {
            #$matches is a hashset of named capture groups, convert to object to allow Select-Object to handle hashset elements as object properties
            [PSCustomObject]$matches
        }
    } | select Database, $Category, Length #| export-csv "AnalysisLengths.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Before I finalized the script, I was trying to use the `Select-String` cmdlet but could not figure out how to use it, I believe it can achieve the same result in a more eloquent way... this is what I had:

```powershell
##Could this be completed with just the Select-String commandlet instead of Get-Content+ForEach+Select-Object?
Select-String -Path "C:\Path\To\File.txt" `
    -Pattern "DDE(?<Database>\w{3})\d{2}(?<CategoryCode>\d{2})(?<CategoryId>\d{1})\d\s+\d{8}\d{3}(?<Length>\d{3})" `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches
```

Using `-ExpandProperty` should convert the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` `Matches` property into the actual `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match` objects for each line...

see also [Powershell Select-Object vs ForEach on Select-String results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362798/powershell-select-object-vs-foreach-on-select-string-results)

Comment: as the file to parse is rather large, if you have optimization suggestions - these are also very welcome.

Comment: my original command, no regex, no mapping, file had been preprocessed only needed to skip first line: `gc "C:\Path\To\File.txt" | select -skip 1 | % { write "$($_.substring(3,3)),$($_.substring(8,2)),$($_.substring(10,2)),$($_.substring(‌​88,3))" } > out.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `Select-String` can combine `Get-Content` and pattern matching, you still need a loop for constructing your custom objects. You could stick with what you have, although I'd suggest a couple modifications. Replace the `switch` statement with a hashtable and make the nested `if` a `Where-Object` filter:

```
$categories = @{
  '50' = 'A'
  '54' = 'C'
  '60' = 'F'
  '66' = 'I'
  '74' = 'M'
  '88' = 'T'
}

$category = @{
  Name       = 'Category'
  Expression = { $categories[$_.CategoryCode] + $_.CategoryId }
}

$pattern = 'DDE(?<Database>\w{3})\d{2}(?<CategoryCode>\d{2})(?<CategoryId>\d{1})\d\s+\d{8}\d{3}(?<Length>\d{3})'

Get-Content 'C:\path\to\file.txt' |
  ? { $_ -match $pattern } |
  % { [PSCustomObject]$matches } |
  select Database, $category, Length |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

Or you could go with [@JPBlanc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30420277/1630171)'s suggestion (again with some slight modifications):

```
$category = @{
  '50' = 'A'
  '54' = 'C'
  '60' = 'F'
  '66' = 'I'
  '74' = 'M'
  '88' = 'T'
}

$pattern = "DDE(?<Database>\w{3})\d{2}(?<CategoryCode>\d{2})(?<CategoryId>\d{1})\d\s+\d{8}\d{3}(?<Length>\d{3})"

Select-String -Path 'C:\path\to\file.txt' -Pattern $pattern | % {
  New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    Database = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
    Category = $category[$_.Matches.Groups[2].Value] + $_.Matches.Groups[3].Value
    Length   = $_.Matches.Groups[4].Value
  }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

The latter will give you slightly better performance, although not too much (execution times were 2:35 vs 2:50 for a 120 MB input file on my test box).

Comment: Thank you, you're right, the `Where-Object` is much more suited I should not have used the if statement as filter. Thank you also for the benchmark, but I find the change in the way the category column is converted a little less readable.

Comment: @VincentDeSmet You can define the calculated property as a variable like you did before (see updated answer). That doesn't have a noticable impact on performance.

Comment: Thank you, I did upvote your answer, there is the trade off between how easy a line is to remember and depending on how large the file is and the performance of the script. I did note in my comment that I was interested in performance comparisons as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way (I'am not so proud of it)

```
Select-String -Path "C:\Path\To\File.txt" -Pattern "DDE(?<Database>\w{3})\d{2}(?<CategoryCode>\d{2})(?<CategoryId>\d{1})\d\s+\d{8}\d{3}(?<Length>\d{3})" | %{New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Database=$_.matches.groups[1];CategoryCode=$_.matches.groups[2];CategoryId=$_.matches.groups[3];Length=$_.matches.groups[4]}} | export-csv "C:\Path\To\File.csv"
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I had a hunch we'd have to use New-Object cmdlet. I'm sad we can't use the names I gave to the capture groups, or can we
? I also would like to avoid repetition having to assign "Database", "Category" again in the object creation. Please note that you're missing the conversion of CategoryId (mapped) + CategoryCode as you can see in my switch statement. Also, I think a oneliner is nice, but I feel that in this case readability suffers. If you feel like working on it a bit more let me know. I'll need to make time to test and accept answer at a later date.

Comment: I full agree that this is not the answer, it's a very ugly one liner, I perhaps work on it this evening (french time).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you have limited your question to `Select-String` cmdlet. If you had included the `switch` statement, then, I'd answer to you: **YES! It's possible!**

And I'd present to you this **simple and short PowerShell code**:

```powershell
$(switch -Regex -File $fileIN{$patt{[pscustomobject]$matches|select * -ExcludeProperty 0}})|epcsv $fileCSV`
```

where `$fileIN` is the input file, `$fileCSV` is CSV file you wanna create, and `$patt` is the pattern you have in your OP:

```
$patt='DDE(?<Database>\w{3})\d{2}(?<CategoryCode>\d{2})(?<CategoryId>\d{1})\d\s+\d{8}\d{3}(?<Length>\d{3})'`
```

The switch statement is very powerful.

Comment: I agree with you, Switch statement is a powerfull statement. I take my hat off to you (yes we still keep kind of hats here in france ;o) ) using swith really gives a one liner (not so readable but ok). **But please** stop beeing so agressive, we try to help each other here with ou experience and up to our knowledge.  Aggressiveness brings to nothing good.

Comment: thank you for your succint solution and the time you took to write it. However, I agree with @JPBlanc, there is no need for personal vendetta's on SO.

Comment: I'm willing to accept this as the correct answer if you remove personal attacks in your answer as well as delete your comments on Ansgar answer below.

Comment: @VincentDeSmet Did you actually try it? Although the syntax is undoubtedly elegant, execution time was more than 14 minutes (compared to less than 3 minutes for the other approaches) for my 120 MB sample file. Plus, it had a *way* bigger memory footprint

Comment: sorry, you are right, I did not have time to try it and accepted pure on how eloquent the solution looks. I uncheck until I actually try it.
performance of course depends on file size and as long as my file isn't too big and performance is acceptable, a more readable or easier to remember line is preferred.